# Does 'Thanks to offered' sound ok?

Tags: colloquial-language

Is it ok to say *Thanks to offered* in this context:

> **Thanks to offered** functionality and versatility. . . .

Comment: This question is probably answerable as-is, but in general it's best to provide complete sentences as examples in questions like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lack of context here that makes the phrase ambiguous.  If the person is actually thanking someone for functionality and versatility that he offered, you might say "Thanks for the offered functionality and versatility" or "Thanks for the functionality and versatility that you have offered."  You wouldn't use "to" in this case, as you can see.

If you are saying (as is more likely) that the offered functonality and versatility causes something to occur, a full sentence might read something like this (let's say we are talking about a software purchase):

> Thanks to the functionality and versatility which is offered by the new software, we may expect our data entry overhead to diminish 20 percent.

or

> Thanks to the offered functionality and versatility of the new software, we may expect our data entry overhead to diminish 20 percent.

Answer (score 1):

It's theoretically possible for it to be correct, depending on the larger context; "offered" is actually a modifier for "functionality and versatility", which are the object of the preposition *to*.  So 'thanks to offered' isn't really a valid fragment;  it's 'thanks (to (offered functionality)) ...'.

But! It's much more likely that you'd prefer to say something along the lines of

> Thanks to the functionality and versatility offered by [whatever feature/upgrade you're promoting], ...

Comment: This is another possibility; you can leave out the "which is" in my example above.